# Finding node log file location programmatically

Tags: ros, c++, log4cxx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible to programmatically find location of the log file where my current ros node is writing?  I am using ros groovy. I would like to find the location of the log file from my C++ code, not from the terminal. I think I found how to find the log file directory by using ros::file_log::getLogDirectory(). However this does not give me the log file name.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/107341/finding-node-log-file-location-programmatically/) by [rsafonov](https://answers.ros.org/users/4799/rsafonov/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-12-05

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rsafonov](https://answers.ros.org/users/4799/rsafonov/) on 2013-12-05**:
Thank you very much for your answer. However my question was different. I would like to find the location of the log file from my C++ code, not from the terminal. I think I found how to find the log file directory by using ros::file_log::getLogDirectory(). However this does not give me the log file name.

**Comment by [Eman](https://answers.ros.org/users/6115/eman/) on 2013-12-05**:
It may help if you tag c++ & other tags that related to your question in your original question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

you can

- type command  `roscore` in the terminal
- then open another separate  new
  terminal & type command `roscd log`

`roscd log` **will take you to the folder where ROS stores log files**

---

Originally posted by [Eman](https://answers.ros.org/users/6115/eman/) with karma: 164 on 2013-12-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rsafonov](https://answers.ros.org/users/4799/rsafonov/) on 2013-12-05**:
Thank you very much for your answer. However my question was different. I would like to find the location of the log file from my C++ code, not from the terminal. I think I found how to find the log file directory by using ros::file_log::getLogDirectory(). However this does not give me the log file name.

**Comment by [Eman](https://answers.ros.org/users/6115/eman/) on 2013-12-05**:
not at all
I am sorry if  I can't help you . I hope to solve it soon
You can declare your question by editting that what you mentioned about"   you want to  find the location of the log file from your C++ code, not from the terminal. I think I found how to find the log file directory by using ros::file_log::getLogDirectory(). However this does not give me the log file name." to your original question

**Comment by [rsafonov](https://answers.ros.org/users/4799/rsafonov/) on 2013-12-05**:
Thank you. I have edited my original question.